# How to make $location.path work on second click

Tags: angularjs

I have this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ncSSFlG1YcwAMmpl9WDX) which works fine on my first search click. But for my second search click nothing happens, `$location.path` stays the same as it is already on the same path i.e `/search`

How to make angular understand to work on more than one clicks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I was struggling with this issue for a long time and have finally solved the answer.

```
app.controller ('setSearch',function($scope,$location,$route,queryService)   {

  $scope.getQuery = function(message){
 queryService.setUserQuery(message);
 $location.path( "/search" );
 $route.reload();
  };

});
```

Addding '$route.reload()` did the trick. Didnt expect such a simple solution. :)